# Freshdesk: Is there a way to automate a private note in Freschat, being copied and ending up in the discussions tab on Freshdesk

Tags: automation, freshdesk, freshchat

Our company uses both freshdesk and Freshchat and rely heavily on in depth notes from agents about the customers situation.

Because we use both Freshchat and desk, we create tickets from chat that agents action on desk. We currently utilise the Discussion tab to allow up to date note keeping on the customers situation. Within a Freshchat session, agents also leave private notes with troubleshooting steps, information etc.

Is there we can automate the copy of a private note in Freshchat across to the discussions tab in freshdesk?

Truly not sure how to tackle this. It would be an advanced automation from within Freshchat, but I’m unsure on how to get the private note into Discussion tab - as it’s not a field that can be added to with normal automations.